# Folding bicycles on Netherlands trains

Tags: public-transport, transportation, netherlands, bicycles

I read that, if you want to take your bicycle on a train in the Netherlands, you must buy ticket for it and, during rush hours, you aren't allowed to take it on the train.

However, folding bicycles don't require a ticket. Does the rush-hour rule also apply to folding bicycles? Or, is it considered to be luggage, so that you are allowed to take them on the train at anytime?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [this site](http://www.holland-cycling.com/planning-your-trip/getting-around/rail):

> Folding bikes - as long as they are folded - are considered luggage
>   and can be taken free of charge any time of the day.

Since a folding bike is considered as luggage, you can take it at any time. This is in common with other train transport systems, such as [London transport](https://tfl.gov.uk/modes/cycling/cycling-in-london/bikes-on-public-transport).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Do you know a place or market in Netherlands I can get used one ?

Comment: @AhmedRagheb: Try [Marktplaats](http://www.marktplaats.nl/z.html?query=vouwfiets&postcode=) (Dutch search term prefilled), or try your luck by walking into any bike repair shop and ask for "vouwfiets".

Comment: I can verify from personal experience that you can take foldable bikes during rush hour, although it can occasionally be difficult to find the spot. A good alternative can be the "OV-fiets". For 10euro ypu can buy an annual ticket and then you cannrent a bike for 4euro a day at most larger stations. @Ahmed_Ragheb